# How to track the element where a delegate is actually clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, html-table

Given a table row (TR). Whenever a user clicks on a table row I want to check the checkbox, similar to as seen on Google Drive / Google Docs.

The exception is with the checkbox or any `<a>` tags as they have different actions... If the user clicks of the checkbox or `<a>` tag I do not want the checkbox to auto check/uncheck. How can I setup a binding that trackings the click and lets the code know whether to select the checkbox or to ignore as it is a checkbox or `<a>` tag click?

Example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xHKUZ/1/

**Sample Code:**

```
<table>
<tr>
        <td class="selector">
            <input type="checkbox" name="folders" value="67">
        </td>
        <td class="name">
            <a>Item 15</a>
        </td>
        <td class="creator">
            <span class="creator">Your Name</span>
        </td>
        <td class="last_modified">
            <time class="" datetime="2012-11-11T00:08:09Z">Nov-10 4:08 PM</time>
        </td>
        <td class="actions">
            <div class="actions-group">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="icon-gear">Settings</i>
                    <i class="icon-caret"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropright">
                    <li><a data-rename="true">Rename</a></li>
                    <li><a data-archive="true">Delete</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

​

Comment: You want to do what? To see exactly which element was clicked, use [`e.target`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/xHKUZ/4/).

Comment: Thanks but that's the problem. The console is logging when you click the checkbox or the a tag which is what I don't want.

Comment: Hence the *first* part of my comment: what do you want to do? I don't follow the question you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("table").delegate("td", "click", function(e) {
  console.log(e);
  // e.delegateTarget === your table element
  // e.currentTarget === the td clicked
  // e.target === the actual element that you clicked
});​
```

You should just be able to check the node type of `e.target` to get your desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `e.stopPropagation` on those elements which you don't want to handle the row click. See below,

**Option 1:**

```
$("table").on('click', '.noclick', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}).on("click", "td", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="noclick" name="folders" value="67">
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xHKUZ/7/

**Option 2:**

In case if you want block the whole `TD`, then you can simply

```
$("table").on('click', 'td:not(.noclick)', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

or Simply handle it yourself.

```
$("table").on('click', 'td', function (e) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('noclick')) { return; }
    console.log(e);
});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <td class="selector noclick">
     <input type="checkbox" name="folders" value="67">
 </td>
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/xHKUZ/16/

Answer (score 0):

Jquery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method:

```
$("table").on("click", "input", function(event){
   var clicked_checkbox = $(this);
});
```

Comment: I want to check the row's checkbox when the user clicks on the row unless the user clicked on a checkbox or <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
$("tr").click(function(event){
    if(!$(event.srcElement).is("a"))
    {
        var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
        $(checkbox).prop("checked",!$(checkbox).prop("checked"));
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwk6W/1/

Answer (score -1):

If you want another function to fire when the user clicks either the `a` or `checkbox`, without triggering the "default" function, simply return `false` on these other functions, for example:

```
$("table").delegate("td", "click", function(e) {
    // Default stuff...
    console.log(e);
});

$( 'a' ).click( function() {
    // Do something else...
    return false;
});

$( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).click( function() {
    // Do something else...
    return false;
});
```

​